# how to compare a nested dictionary with list of nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

how to check target dictionary is present in list of nested dictionaries.
only particular key details and books and their values needs to be checked.

```
target = {'details' : [{'name':'Ron','description':{'grade':'seven','section':'A'},'level':1}],
'Books':{'type':'Horror','id':101},
'version_id':{'version':10,'enable':true},
Total_marks':700}

list_of_dict = [
{'details' : [{'name':'jeff','description':{'grade':'six','section':'B'},'level':1}],
'Books':{'type':'Fiction','id':101},
'version_id':{'version':11,'enable':true},
Total_marks':900},

{'details' : [{'name':'Ron','description':{'grade':'seven','section':'A'},'level':1}],
'Books':{'type':'Horror','id':101},
'version_id':{'version':12,'enable':true},
Total_marks':700}]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you need, do you just need a yes/no answer for example? And what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Python knows well how to compare dictionaries.

What about using a simple:

```
target in list_of_dict
```

output: `True`